Is it recommended to use async operation to fetch data from database?
I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application and need to fetch a user from a database based on their username. This involves querying a User table to retrieve the user's details. Given that database operations can be time-consuming and may block the main thread, I'm considering using asynchronous processing. Should I use asynchronous methods for this database query to improve performance and responsiveness? Additionally, what are the benefits of using asynchronous methods in this scenario?
public User GetUserByUsername(string username)
{
    User user = null;

    user = _users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username.Equals(username));

    if (user != null)
    {
        return user; // Return from memory 
    }

    // If not found in memory, retrieve from database
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("GetUserByUsername", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);

            con.Open();
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    user = new User
                    {
                        UserId = (int)reader["UserId"],
                        Username = reader["Username"].ToString(),
                        PasswordHash = reader["PasswordHash"].ToString(),
                        Salt = reader["Salt"].ToString(),
                        CreatedAt = (DateTime)reader["CreatedAt"]
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return user;
}

I have written the below code. Was just wondering about others opinion on it.
public async Task<User> GetUserByUsernameAsync(string username)
{
    User user = null;

    try
    {
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("GetUserByUsername", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);

                // Open the connection asynchronously
                await con.OpenAsync();

                // Execute the query asynchronously
                using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    if (await reader.ReadAsync())
                    {
                        user = new User
                        {
                            UserId = (int)reader["UserId"],
                            Username = reader["Username"].ToString(),
                            PasswordHash = reader["PasswordHash"].ToString(),
                            Salt = reader["Salt"].ToString(),
                            CreatedAt = (DateTime)reader["CreatedAt"]
                        };
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle exceptions as per your application's error handling strategy
        Console.WriteLine($"Error fetching user: {ex.Message}");
    }

    return user;
}


BTW you can replace almost all of this code with Dapper and eg : var user=await con.QueryAsync<User>("GetUserByUsername",new {Username=username});

You should, but not to improve performance, at least not directly. HTTP requests in ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core are processed by threads that come from a thread pool. By using asynchronous operations you release the request thread to process other requests.
Blocking isn't cheap and actually consumes CPU, because all blocks actually start with spinwaits. First of all, Windows IO is natively asynchronous, with synchronous operations emulated by blocking. Putting a thread to sleep and rescheduling them is an expensive operation. Blocks are supposed to be short lived,  so .NET (and Windows) will start any block with a spinwait before putting the thread to sleep.
Less blocking means you can use the same amount of threads and CPU power to server a higher number of concurrent requests.
BTW you can reduce your code to almost a single line by using Dapper:
using var con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
var user=await con.QueryAsync<User>("GetUserByUsername",new {Username=username});
return user;

and with a bit of pattern matching :
public User GetUserByUsername(string username)
{
    if(_users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username==username) is {} u)
    {
        return u;
    };
    using var con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
    var user=await con.QueryFirstAsync<User>("GetUserByUsername",new {
        Username=username
    });
    return user;
}

Dapper will create parameters based on the argument type's properties and types, call the query or stored procedure and map the results

"​Blocking isn't cheap and actually consumes CPU, because all blocks actually start with spinwaits." -- Could you provide a sense of magnitude regarding the CPU consumption caused by spinning before blocking? Are we talking about milliseconds, microseconds or nanoseconds? How much a typical ASP.NET application is harmed by the spinning, in terms of % increase in response time or % decrease in throughput? Also would it be beneficial to replace the lock with an alternative synchronization mechanism that doesn't spin-wait before blocking?

Also could you identify the calls in the first code fragment provided by the OP, the synchronous fragment, that are blocking calls and start with spin-waits? For example do the con.Open() and reader.Read() calls belong in this category?

30 servers out of 100, or avoiding a cascading meltdown of all 100. You know I've mentioned that example several times over the past 10 years, and I used that in conference talks and meetups.

"30 servers out of 100" -- Could you elaborate? Do you mean that the spinning that precedes blocking, alone, amounts to 30% of the total work done by an ASP.NET server?

@TheodorZoulias con.Open ends up doing network IO if there is no open connection in the pool. cmd.ExecuteReader always does. reader.Read may do if the next row is not in the buffer (can contain multiple rows). Any sync network IO ends up calling the recv Winsock function, which waits in the kernel. That wait usually starts with a spinwait, due to how long it can take to reschedule the thread, it's a performance benefit not a cost to use a spinwait.

@Charlieface do you know the purpose of the spin-wait? Is it to avoid putting the thread to sleep and awakening it, in case the I/O operation completes extremely quickly, like 1 microsecond or less? What kind of I/O can ever complete so quickly?

@TheodorZoulias I think many IO requests could complete that quickly: the driver may hold it in a RAM buffer, the network adapter (or disk driver) may and often do hold an internal memory buffer as well, and SSD drives are exceedingly fast these days.

This post is 100% correct.  The other huge elephant in the room? You post back and round trip MUST wait for all operations to 100% complete before the web page can travel back to the browser.  In effect you must wait which in most cases defeats the purpose of asynchronous operations.  If your doing a update then in theory you don't need to wait (assuming you don't need to display the results of the update in the current page). For a data pull you have to wait,  and thus asynchronous data pulls don't help much,  and tossing in asynchronous overhead you in a losing scenario and no gains

@AlbertD.Kallal pleased don't advocate for fire-and-forget. Or, if you insist, at least do it not in a comment but in an answer, so that the community can downvote your post as needed.

Not at all suggesting fire and forget.  The simple matter is due to the post back model,  then a asynchronous data query does not gain an reduction in say a frozen ui like it can for desktop software.  Since the page is being processed up on the server without user seeing any updates or even partial updates until browser round trip completes then a asynchronous data pull is of little use.  Of course some exceptions such as calling web methods may benefit , but general code in most cases are stuck in what amounts to a transaction that must complete 100% and that round trip is no asynchronous.

From the asp.net team:

Async events in web applications are inherently strange beasts. Async void is meant for a fire and forget programming model. This works in Windows UI applications since the application sticks around until the OS kills it, so whenever the async callback runs there is guaranteed to be a UI thread that it can interact with. In web applications, this model falls apart since requests are by definition transient. If the async callback happens to run after the request has finished, there is no guarantee that the data structures the callback needs to interact with are still in a good state.

Thus why fire and forget (and async void) is inherently a bad idea in web applications.

​@AlbertD.Kallal async void is fire-and-crash, not fire-and-forget. An unhandled exception thrown in an async void method crashes the process. Fire-and-forget is to launch a Task, and neither Wait nor await it. Which is what you suggest as being an advantage of asynchronous over synchronous code. It's not. You can fire-and-forget synchronous code too (for example with Task.Run), and it's an equally bad advice.
